# Redirection based on user type - vue router

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication, vue-router

I am a beginner in vue and I need your help please. I am creating an application where the login is connected to firebase. I would like to use vue-router to redirect a user to a particular page. When a person logs in whose user.role = "admin" it should be redirected to "/admin". Every other logged person to "/" and non-logged in people are redirected to "/login" page.
Here are parts of my code:

**main.js**

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {  
  const currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;  
  const requiresAuth = to.meta.requiresAuth;
  if (requiresAuth && !currentUser){ next({ name: 'Login' })} 
  else if (!requiresAuth && currentUser) {next({name: 'Dashboard'}), console.log(currentUser)} 
  else next();
});
```

**authStore.js**

```
const actions = { 
  logIn({ dispatch,commit,rootGetters }){
      firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(async (user) => {
        if (user) {       
          commit('SET_USER', user);

         var uid = user.uid;
            db.collection('users').doc(uid)
            .get()
            .then((doc)=>{
            commit('gutscheinStore/SET_USER_ROLE', doc.data().role, {root:true})
            commit('gutscheinStore/SET_USER_STANDORT_ID', doc.data().standortID, {root: true})
            commit('gutscheinStore/SET_USER_BETREIBER_ID', doc.data().betreiberID, {root: true})
                //console.log(rootGetters['gutscheinStore/getUserRole'])
              })
   
          router.push('/')
        } else {
          console.log("No entry without login")
        }
      })
  },
```

**index.js** in **router**

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Dashboard',
    component: Dashboard,
    meta: {
      requiresAuth: true,
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/login',
    name: 'Login',
    component: Login
  },
  {
    path: '/admin',
    name:'AdminDashboard',
    component: AdminDashboard,
    meta: {
      requiresAuth: true,
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In `authStore.js` where you currently have the line `router.push("/")`:

```
const actions = { 
          ...
          // snipped for clarity
   
          router.push('/')
        } else {
          console.log("No entry without login")
        }
      })
  },
```

You could instead change this as follows:

```
const actions = { 
          ...
          // snipped for clarity

          if(user.role === "admin") { 
            router.push("/admin")
          } else {
            router.push("/")
          }
        } else {
          // router.push("/login")
          router.go()
        }
      })
  },
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately it doesn`t work. I have an error:

"Uncaught (in promise) NavigationDuplicated: Avoided redundant navigation to current location: "/login"."

Comment: In that case you can probably use `router.go()`. Which should just refresh the login page. But you'll want to do something to show the user that something didn't work. Usually people setup an error page, a forgotten password flow, or a toast.